# Alternative to $geoNear MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

i'm working on a API. one of my endpoint return me the **Spots** around a point defined by a `LONGITUDE` & `LATITUDE` coords ordered by pages. I also send a `PAGE_SIZE` for a number or **Spots** to return and a `MIN_DISTANCE` from where to start the page that is the last item of the last page.

I'm using the **$geoNear** key to do that, it's convenient cause it also return me the distance for the center that i use to do the paging.

Sadly i'm now hosting the DB on azure COSMOS DB and it seems that the **$geoNear** is not supported.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support-36#aggregation-stages

what's would be the best alternative to get the most similar result? there is a bunch or **key** that sounds good but can't figure out the best option: (**$geoWithin, $geoIntersects, $near, $nearSphere, $geometry**)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support-36#geospatial-operators

```
Spots.aggregate
    ([
      {
        $geoNear: {
          near: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [ LONGITUDE, LATITUDE ]
          },
          distanceField: "location.distance",
          spherical: true,
          minDistance: MIN_DISTANCE,
          maxDistance: DISTANCE * 1000,
          query: {
            $and: [
              ...
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      { $match: {} },
      { $limit : PAGE_SIZE},
      ...
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Would be `$near` or `$nearSphere`.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally used **$nearSphere** and got almost the same result except the distance that i'll calculate manually.

```
Spots.aggregate(
    [
      {
        $match: {
          $and: [
            {
              location: {
                $nearSphere: {
                  $geometry: {
                      type : "Point",
                      coordinates : [ LONGITUDE, LATITUDE ]
                  },
                  $minDistance: MIN_DISTANCE,
                  $maxDistance: MIN_DISTANCE * 1000
                }
              }
            },
            ...
          ]
        }
      },
      { $limit : PAGE_SIZE},
      ...
```